# android project phonegap intellij cordova imports not recognized

Tags: cordova, intellij-idea, import

I was developing a mobile app (to android/iphone) using EclipseIDE/Phonegap/cordova, bur I have changed to Intellij 12. It seems that everything works except that the cordova import are not being recognized. What could be the problem/solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include `cordova-2.9.0.jar` (libs folder) and set "Add as library" (right click) ?

These tutorials might help you:

[Android, Intellij IDEA and PhoneGap: Getting Started](http://therockncoder.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/android-intellij-idea-and-phonegap.html).
[How to use PhoneGap with IntellijIDEA](http://nick.perfectedz.com/2012/10/02/how-to-use-phonegap-with-intellijidea/)

Your Activity should look something like this:

```
package com.example.Androide;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MyActivity extends DroidGap {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```